# Twitter bootstrap: active tabs are still underlined

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using twitter's Bootstrap css to create a basic tabbed nav, as shown [here](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/components.html#navs) under "Basica tabs." You'll notice that the active tab is not underlined, which makes it feel like it is in the foreground. When I use the exact same code, my active tabs are still underlined, which really undermines the effectiveness.

I've created a JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/s_d_p/nRB5t/1/

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="row" style="width:960px;">          
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs span12">
            <li class="text-center active"><a href="howitworks.php" class="">HOW IT WORKS</a></li>
            <li class=" text-center"><a href="#" class=""><small>Login</small></a></li>
            <li class=" text-center"><a href="" class=""><small>Join</small></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lose the `<small>` tags and it works fine.

Comment: Cool. But why does small change it?

Comment: It makes the font size smaller which throws off the alignment on the borders.

Comment: I'm aware it changes the font size, wondering if you could fill me in on why it throws the border out. From a quick test (simple `<small>` text inside a `<p>` element, it actually makes the parent a pixel bigger. Do you know why?

Comment: Inspect the elements in the chrome debugger or in firebug if you use firefox. bootstrap.css sets the font size of `<small>` tags to 85% I think.

Comment: That did it! Thanks. I'm still a little fuzzy on why the `<small>` breaks the border styles.

Answer (score 1):

As answered by [Rob](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17355182/707117), removing the small tag will correct it. If you would like to keep the styling though, you could change the font size on the anchor styling for inactive menu items (and set it to the def 100% on the active one so it stays at the proper size):

```
.nav-tabs > li > a {
    font-size: 85%;
}

.nav-tabs > .active > a, .nav-tabs > .active > a:hover, .nav-tabs > .active > a:focus {

    font-size: 100%;
}
```

In fact, as a few [online articles](http://line25.com/articles/youre-doing-it-wrong-common-html-tag-misuse) ([and the MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/small)) suggest, `<small>` has been re-purposed in HTML 5 to indicate fine print, copyright and legal print, and side-comments. So the above would be a more proper way to achieve the styling you're after anyway.